Firestore Security Rules - Emulator Update/Get Requests with Empty Resource
I'm trying to learn Firebase Security Rules for Firestore. Not to mention the extreme lack of clarity in the docs, I'm struggling to make sense of these random UPDATE / GET requests that have no resource attached.
From what I've read, the resource object is a reference to what's in the database already. If it's an UPDATE or a GET request, it should exist. So, something like,
allow update: if resource.data.id != null;

should work fine and never generate an error.
But it clearly is not working. Follow below:
In my Firebase emulator, under Firestore > Requests, there are several UPDATE / GET requests failing with an Error:

When I opened one up, to figure out why it's failing, I noted that the resource object that should contain something is somehow an error:

What is going on here? What kind of request would cause resource to be an empty object? Is this behavior documented?
EDIT:
If it helps, here is essentially the code (with unaffecting parts redacted), indicating where the failure is happening, presumably because resource.data.email is an error that propagates to the condition root:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function loggedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    // ...

    match /path/{objectId} {

      allow get: if loggedIn() // <---------------------------
          && request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email;

      // ...

      allow update: if loggedIn() // <---------------------------
          && request.resource.data.id == objectId
          && request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email
          && request.resource.data.email == resource.data.email;
    }

    // ...

  }
}

Ok, it appears that a single GET request triggers a failing GET request and a succeeding GET request in the list. I might suppose that Firebase runs the rule once without the resource to see if it passes without needing a read, but if not, runs a read and then runs it again.. But I cannot find any documentation for this.
I did find an open GitHub issue, though, that matches my case pretty much exactly:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6252
Thanks

Please edit the question to state exactly what you did to get the unexpected results that you observed.  We should be able to take your instructions and reproduce the same behavior.  The security rule itself won't leave these logs - indeed it doesn't do anything until there is some query that it might intercept.

Please edit your question to show the path you're updating, the existing document data at that path and the patch you're performing to that data. You should typically be able to fit this in one (rather large) screenshot.

@DougStevenson, I'll try to update it. Frankly I didn't write the code, though. I would never expect resource to be an Error for an UPDATE, but clearly there's a case where it is. I'm really asking for what that case in fact is (not even so much how to fix it). Maybe it is something client-side? What would such a client-side request look like?
@FrankvanPuffelen, this is a proprietary application. I am not permitted to release much information other than the above, but I'll see about fudging it if you think that would help.

It appears to be a bug?
As I mention in my question, I did find an open GitHub issue that matches my case:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6252
It may be that Firebase released some update to try to save on reads. i.e., Maybe it tries once without reading the target document to see if it fails without an error (i.e., direct false / permission denied response). Otherwise (if it gets an Error), it tries again with a read.
I have no evidence to back this up, though. So, please, if anyone has more information or documentation, write an answer and I'll accept it.

I seem to have the exact same issue with my emulator. Just like you though, it seems it fails on one attempt and then succeeds on the next without any logs.
